# Restore Windows on Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows, ubuntu, restore

A few years back, my parents gave me a Windows 8 laptop. After years and years of messing with the poor thing, I got it to a hardly working point, and it seemed Windows hardly even worked on it anymore. Because of this, I attempted to factory reset my laptop, just for the same weird errors and glitches to show up. Finally, I installed Ubuntu, and the errors stopped. After using the laptop for a year now, I still hardly know how to use Ubuntu, and I think that I should switch back to Windows 8 and attempt to fix it's problems. I was wondering if it is possible to get Windows 8 back on my Ubuntu for free? Thanks -Aiden

Answer (score 1):

I assume the computer has a valid license in place, since Windows 8 came with the computer, so just download the Windows 8 ISO from Microsoft, use the bootable USB-program, run the install, and presto, you'll have a new install.

You can find the bootable USB-program here: http://wudt.codeplex.com/

Then you need an ISO of Windows 8, from somewhere... here for instance: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows8

Download the ISO, run the bootable USB-program, boot from the USB-drive on your computer, and install Windows, formatting the drive etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways of doing this - the core of your problem is most likely that the hard drive has been partitioned and allocated to Ubuntu.   The easiest way to fix this - if its the last thing you intend to do on Ubuntu **AND YOU ARE INTENDING TO WIPE ALL THE DATA**  is to zero the partitioning on the ubuntu box.  ** THIS WILL CAUSE EVERYTHING ON THE BOX TO BECOME INACCESSIBLE UNTIL THE NEW OS IS INSTALLED - AND ALL OLD DATA WILL BE LOST ** is to

1. Make sure no external usb keys or drives or other storage are attached to the box and boot it up.
2. Open a terminal window.  You can do this by clicking on the "Ubuntu Swirl" at the top left of the box, and typing "Terminal", then clicking on the icon to launch it.
3. Erase the partition and boot sector information to reset everything to appear empty - This is the dangerous part. In the black terminal window box, issue the command

> dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1

4. Wait 30 seconds (for it to write to the disk) and then turn off the computer.   When you reboot it will appear to be totally empty and you can install Windows from scratch.

(The correct way would be to do a similar version of this process using a USB key with a Linux based OS, but I've not gone into this because its more complex and raises issues about finding the /dev/sdX block.).